# How to determine groups of points

Tags: algorithm, grouping, aggregation, points

Assume that I have a coordinate system with points. Human can determine, that they are arranged into aggregations. Is there any algorithm which can divide these points into groups? Here is an illustrative example:

[image: grouped points]

Comment: Lots: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURE_data_clustering_algorithm#CURE_clustering_algorithm, http://biocomp.bioen.uiuc.edu/oscar/tools/Hierarchical_Clustering.html, serach for "data clustering"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of a very general class of problems known as [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_clustering). Given the immense amount of research done on this topic, I doubt a single answer would suffice without knowing more about the problem.

I would suggest you start looking at some basic ones such as [k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_algorithm).

If you can use a library, [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) is also an excellent choice.